# Remote event not sending from client to server

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make an announcement system in Roblox Studio using remote events to transmit the data but the remote events arent firing.

Local Script (ADMIN):

```
...
game.ReplicatedStorage.SG_FlightAnnouncementSystem.Events.startAnnouncement:FireServer(announcement)
print("Client Sent Announcement")
```

Script (SERVER SCRIPT SERVICE):

```
local announcementReciever = script.Parent.Parent.Events.startAnnouncement
local announcementSender = script.Parent.Parent.Events.startClientAnnouncement

announcementReciever.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, announcement)
    print("Server Received Announcement")
    script.Parent.Parent["Sound Effects"].announcementChime.Playing = true
    
    announcementSender:FireAllClients(announcement)
end)
```

Local Script (CLIENT RECIEVER):

```
startClientAnnouncement.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(announcement)
    print("Client Received Announcement")
end)
```

I expect it to output 2 client prints and 1 server print but I only get 1 client print from firing the event.

Comment: Where are your LocalScripts located?

Comment: Both are in screenguis, different ones because the sender bis in an admin only gui and the receiver is in a announcement gui

Answer (score 0):

In your LocalScript, you fire the event located in ReplicatedStorage :

`game.ReplicatedStorage.SG_FlightAnnouncementSystem.Events.startAnnouncement`

But in your Script in ServerScriptService, you register a listener to an event that is also in ServerScriptService :

`local announcementReciever = script.Parent.Parent.Events.startAnnouncement`

To solve this issue, I would double check that your Script is actually in ServerScriptService and not ReplicatedStorage. And if that's not the case, I would update the paths of your Script to properly locate the events in ReplicatedStorage.

```lua
local Events = game.ReplicatedStorage.SG_FlightAnnouncementSystem.Events
local announcementReciever = Events.startAnnouncement
local announcementSender = Events.startClientAnnouncement

announcementReciever.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, announcement)
    print("Server Received Announcement")
    script.Parent.Parent["Sound Effects"].announcementChime.Playing = true
    
    announcementSender:FireAllClients(announcement)
end)
```

Comment: Thanks I made sure that it was and it did fix it, my script was setup for ReplicatedStorage by accident.